# Why won't this ListView show ripples when items are clicked? (AppCompat 22)

Tags: android, listview, android-appcompat

I've inherited an Android project that was written without AppCompat. In my efforts to update it using AppCompat (to give it a Material theme), I've found that ripples in list views didn't work. The original author pushed [a commit](https://github.com/HWComputerScience/iHW-Android/commit/87486bf1e78c8db5baae3cd33bf593c4e30b1448) today that somehow fixed the lack of ripples in one area of the app, but neither of us can figure out why this happened. Now I'm trying to add ripples to the preferences screen (entirely Java).

I've seen some posts on SO that suggest setting listSelector to a transparent drawable to disable the ripple, but I'm not sure what to set it to enable the ripple.

Here's what the PreferencesActivity looks like (skipping stuff):

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends IHWActivity implements ListAdapter {
private ListView mainList;
private ArrayList<String> titles;
private ArrayList<String> subtitles;
private int newCampus;
private int newYear;
private TextView yearText;
private CheckBox notificationBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.preferences);

    titles = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    subtitles = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    titles.add(getString(R.string.pref_notifications));
    subtitles.add(getString(R.string.pref_notifications_desc));
    titles.add(getString(R.string.pref_change));
    subtitles.add(getString(R.string.pref_change_desc));
    titles.add(getString(R.string.pref_redownload));
    subtitles.add(getString(R.string.pref_redownload_desc));
    titles.add(getString(R.string.pref_disclaimer));
    subtitles.add(getString(R.string.pref_disclaimer_desc));
    titles.add(getString(R.string.pref_about));
    subtitles.add("");
    mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.preference_list);
    mainList.setDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.divider_horizontal_bright));
    mainList.setAdapter(this);
    newCampus = Curriculum.getCurrentCampus();
    newYear = Curriculum.getCurrentYear();


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_preferences, null);
        TextView titleView = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_preference_title));
        TextView subtitleView = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_preference_subtitle));
        titleView.setText(titles.get(position));
        subtitleView.setText(subtitles.get(position));
        if (subtitles.get(position).equals("")) subtitleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (position == 0) {
            notificationBox = new CheckBox(this);
            notificationBox.setChecked(Curriculum.getNotificationsEnabled());
            notificationBox.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            notificationBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    toggleNotifications(isChecked);
                }
            });
            ((ViewGroup) convertView).addView(notificationBox);
        }
    }
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = mainList.indexOfChild(v);
            if (i == 0) {
                toggleNotifications(!notificationBox.isChecked());
            } else if (i == 1) {
                showYearOptions();
            } else if (i == 2) {
                showRedownloadOptions();
            } else if (i == 3) {
                showDisclaimer();
            } else if (i == 4) {
                showAbout();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Here's the relevant XML (all of list_item_preferences.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_preference_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:linksClickable="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_preference_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:linksClickable="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is something disabling the ripple? Is there supposed to be code that turns it on? The original author had the automatic click selector to add his own one (colored to match the app) when the app was first written (so he would get the default Holo blue selector).

Comment: where is your selector xml? that's the ripple right? if so post it then

Comment: Don't set a click listener on the view itself. Use the ListView click handling.

Comment: @Elltz: the selector xml is currently not a ripple. It's set to a yellow overlay without a ripple. How can I make it a ripple?

Comment: @alanv: Does that mean using  `setOnItemClickListener`? What would I set the listener to for a ripple?

Comment: Yes, use setOnItemClickListener so that the ListView handles touch interaction. If you set a click listener on an individual row, the row will handle touch interaction and you will not get the default list selector (which is what displays the ripple).

Comment: @alanv: Thanks, that solved the issue. This solution will work on pre-Lollipop devices, correct? I know there won't be a ripple, but I want the functionality to remain the same. I'll post my full solution and credit you.

Comment: Yep, this is the standard way to handle clicks in ListView and it will work on all versions.